# Cannot use SASS in my react , I don't want to install node-sass

Tags: reactjs, sass

I keep getting this message

```
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
```

but from google they said node-sass was deprecated already

and even I install node-sass, I got another error

my node version is v18.7.0, also try to remove node_module and run npm install again already

```
{
  "name": "clothing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.54.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader)

> sass-loader requires you to install either Dart Sass, Node Sass on your own (more documentation can be found below) or Sass Embedded.

> ...

> **Note**
>
> We highly recommend using Dart Sass.

So I would suggest to try [Dart Sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass) instead (as stated [here](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass#from-npm) You can add it to your project using `npm install --save-dev sass` or you can install it globally using `npm install -g sass` )

Answer (score 0):

You can install sass by typing

```
npm i sass --save-dev
```

(Keep in mind that node-sass in deprecated and we are using Dart Sass instead of it)
to get more information click on the link below :

[Adding a Sass Stylesheet - Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/)